# Validating multiple form boxes, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make sure each field is filled in, else show an error. When I submit my form it goes through and no error is shown? Can anyone see whats wrong?

here is my form **HTML**

```
<form id="Form" name="Form" method: "post" action: '#' onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <fieldset>
        <label>First name:*<br>
            <input name="fname" id ="fname" type="text"></label><br>
        <label>Last name:*<br>
            <input name="lname" id="lname" type="text"></label><br>
        <label>Email:*<br>
            <input name="email" id="email" type="text"></label><br>
        <label>Phone:<br>
            <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text"></label><br>
        <label>Message:*<br>
            <input id="message" id="message" name="msg" type="text"></label><br>
        <br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="send"><br>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here is my **JS**

```
function validateForm() {
    var errormessage = "";

    if (document.getElementbyID('fname').value == "") {
        errormessage += "enter your first name /n";
        document.getElementById('fname').style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    if (document.getElementbyID('lname').value == "") {
        errormessage += "enter your last name /n";
        document.getElementById('lname').style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    if (document.getElementbyID('email').value == "") {
        errormessage += "enter your email /n";
        document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    if (document.getElementbyID('message').value == "") {
        errormessage += "enter your message /n";
        document.getElementById('message').style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    if (errormessage != "") {
        alert(errormessage);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding a required tag in the html inputs, like `<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required/>`

Answer (score 4):

Open the Developer Tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Ensure that the "Preserve log" option is enabled so the errors are not lost when the form submits.

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyID is not a function

JavaScript is case-sensitive. `ID` is not `Id`. You need to get the names of your function calls correct.

When your JS throws an exception, the function aborts, and form submission continues as normal.

Comment: Thanks, have changed the "id" but still no errors show.

Comment: What does the console say? (because you changed to ID instead of from ID)